# missing some audio channels when rendering

Tags: audio

i'm new to Blender... currently using the Video Editor and running into an odd issue...

i have a long 20+ min edit with exrs as video source and multiple audio sources

but when i render to quicktime "some" of the audio, usually top channel music, does not render.

i didn't have this issue when i had lo-res jpegs as my video source but now with the exr's it's become an issue

any insight into what could be causing this?

thanks!

Comment: Try another audio codec if you can, I had a lot of troubles with AAC, but AC3 worked fine for me

Comment: ok... thanks for the response. i'll give it a try!

Comment: There is also Mixdown option (button "Audio" near "Render Animation" ), it is basically bakes all your audio into one track. So you can bake only audiotrack and then place it in project with EXR's instead of buggy channels

Comment: mixdown is a good thing to know about. not sure if it's an option in this case.

Comment: i've deduced that for some reason Blender is actually lowering the audio levels of top channel audio tracks. in the end i greatly increased the audio volume and it did the trick.  exr's? not sure yet. the codec might also be a good solution. thanks for the help

Comment: If you apply keyframes to audio strips volumes', and you do a long track or have alot of data, usually the keyframes are not respected properly and the audio strips with them either won't be recorded or they will have the wrong volume changes intended.